# get an html element from the title of a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list that has one active class element

```
<ul class="tabs clearfix" >
<li>  
  <a title="abc" href=# >ABC</a> 
</li>
<li>
  <a title="xyx" href=# >XYZ</a>
</li>
<li class=active > 
  <a title="all" href=# >All</a> 
</li>
```

I am using local storage to store the title of a tag which is then used to loadcontent accordingly. I am having difficulty in getting the specific li element when i fetch the titel back from local storage. I would like to add an active class to li element that corresponds to the specific title. Here's the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tabs = $('.tabs > li');
if (localStorage.getItem("tabIndex") === null) {
    $( "#content" ).load( "{{url_for('mypage', query=query)}}" );
}else{
    var lastIndex = localStorage.getItem('tabIndex');
    **Do something to get the specific li element for the title**
    **addclass('active') for the li**
    LoadContent(lastIndex);
} 
tabs.on("click", function(){
    tabs.removeClass('active');
    localStorage.setItem('tabIndex', $('a', this).attr('title'));
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var index = $(this).children('a')[0].title;
    LoadContent(index);
})
});
```

I tried `$("a[title=lastIndex]").parent().addClass('active');` but this doesnt seem to work. As always, I really appreciate all the help that this site provides me. Thanks

Comment: is the missing `</ul>` just a typo here?  Is the missing semi-colon just a typo here: `})` - and I make the assumption that the asterisks notes are just an indicator of where/what you wish to achieve...

Comment: yes. your assumptions are correct. Sorry somehow I missed the tags while pasting the code. The answer below solves my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$('a[title="'+ lastIndex +'"]')` to get the desired element,

Eg: say your **lastIndex = xyz** then the selector becomes `$('a[title="xyz"]')`

Comment: Best add inner double-quotes to allow for any special characters in the title attributes (spaces, minus etc)

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what the plus signs do. I have only seen examples on the web that use a['<titlename>'] to select an item

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks

Comment: so say your lastIndex = xyz then the selector becomes `$('a[title="xyz"]')`

Comment: sorry updated now it should be title="xyx" check the updated one please typo